# Search apache logs for svn access

Tags: apache, svn, logging

I want to rule out the possibility that a hacker might have accessed a SVN repository. Checking for commits is easy enough, just look at the SVN log. However I want to find out if they simply viewed files (such as config files with passwords and API keys) through SVN. I read that SVN doesn't keep access logs, so I have to search through the apache access_log.

I tried doing a grep for our svn subdomain: `grep "svn.our-domain.com" access_log` but it came back with nothing found. I found out that our logs strip out the domain and just show you the file or directory being accessed. I decided to do a grep for the word "trunk" instead, and I got a bunch of hits on directories but no specific files.

Is there a way to get a log of all files accessed through SVN?

Comment: Voting to close as this should be in ServerFault or the security site.

Answer (score 0):

At first, configure logging as described in [Apache logging section of SVNBook](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/httpd/#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.logging). Then parse [high-level log](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/operational-logging/) (i.e. operational log which contains logical operations only).